# What's the best practice to handle daylight saving data published by the AESO in R?

Tags: r

The AESO in Alberta Canada publishes data with the following format:

```
 DateHE = c("11/03/2019 01", "11/03/2019 02", "11/03/2019 02*", "11/03/2019 03",
  "11/03/2019 04", "11/03/2019 05", "11/03/2019 06", "11/03/2019 07",
  "11/03/2019 08", "11/03/2019 09", "11/03/2019 10", "11/03/2019 11",
  "11/03/2019 12", "11/03/2019 13", "11/03/2019 14", "11/03/2019 15",
  "11/03/2019 16", "11/03/2019 17", "11/03/2019 18", "11/03/2019 19",
  "11/03/2019 20", "11/03/2019 21", "11/03/2019 22", "11/03/2019 23", "11/03/2019 24")
```

The hour at the end of the date stands for Hour Ending. These have important information for financial contracts which are based on the hour ending/time range in a day.

What would be the best practice on handling dates and hour ending for data analysis and charting?

What would be the best way to handle

Note: Alberta is in the Mountain daylight saving time zone.

Comment: Why do some of the dates end in `*`?

Comment: For daylight  savings there are two hour ending with 2 ("11/03/2019 02", "11/03/2019 02*") on that day. https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/canada

Comment: That doesn't explain `11/03/2019 10*` or `11/03/2019 18*`.